# C# Component Container

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a windows form and my own class in my project

I have a method in my own class

```
public object Sample(Form MyForm,string ComponentName)
{

}
```

I want to get components of the "MyForm"  from another class How Can I Make THIs?

form class

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

}
```

MyOwnClass

```
public class Sample
{

public object GetComponentMethod(Form form,string ComponentName)
{

////
}

}
```

Comment: Please read this: http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried with:

```
Control myControl= form.controls.Find(...)?
```

**updated**

Sorry but in this case I cannot understand what are you looking for!

**updated**

you have to create a public property Components! So you can retrieve data you need!

Comment: BindingSources or dataset is not in Controls.they are in components.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are just trying to access members of one object from another object.

If so you need to expose some way of accessing a specific instance of a class.

If you will only ever have one instance (of say your Form1) the simplest way is to expose that single instance via a public static property. This is called a singleton pattern:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public static Form1 Singleton { get; private set; }
    public Form1()
    {
        Form1.Singleton = this;
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

You can the access your Form1 instance using `Form1.Singleton.SomeProperty` from anywhere.

*I am not promoting any specific Singleton pattern here, as there are too many issues over thread safety, but for your simple example this will do the job. Call the static property "Singleton" or "This" or "SolutionToMyWoes" or whatever you like!*